# How do I identify where a javascript file is currently being loaded from?

Tags: javascript

Say I have a reference to a javascript file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://blah.com/js/count.js"></script>
```

with the contents of count.js:

```
alert("This script is loading from:" + url);
```

How do I identify the value that should go into the url variable, from inside of count.js?

Answer (score 1):

When an external script is being executed, its `SCRIPT` element would be the last one in the page, which is `document.scripts[document.scripts.length-1]`.

So, if the `SCRIPT` element is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://blah.com/js/count.js"></script>
```

And the `count.js` file contents is:

```
alert("This script is loading from:" + document.scripts[document.scripts.length-1].src);
```

It'll display:

```
This script is loading from: http://blah.com/js/count.js
```

Note that HTML5 introduces an [`async` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/script#Attributes) for `SCRIPT` element, which likely make the above method useless. In case of asynchronous, the only way to get the associated `SCRIPT` element is to use Gecko's (Firefox) [`document.currentScript`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.currentScript), but this is non standard and is not implemented by all other web browser engines. i.e.: Trident (MSIE), WebKit (Chrome/Safari), Presto (Opera).